# Jquery Slider on mouseup event

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using jquery-1.7.1.js and jquery.slider.js

```
 jQuery('#Slider1').slider({ from: 0, to: maxAmount, smooth: true, step: 100,round: 0,
          onstatechange: function( value ){
    ....
    }
```

this function is called when slider is sliding by mouse.
I want same slider function with event sliding release (like mouseup) instead of onstatechange.

Please suggest..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use callback for the mouseup event

```
jQuery('#Slider1').slider({ from: 0, to: maxAmount, smooth: true, step: 100,round: 0,
      callback: function( value ){
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The slider has a `stop` event to handle this:

```
$('#slider').slider({ ..., stop: function(event, ui){ }, ... });
```